# why is the loop repeating (seemingly randomly) after the function should have completed?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

I have been trying to write a programme to draw pairs of names 'out of a hat'.  Its for family present buying and therefore has some 'exemptions' due to living in the same house. Each person on the list of names will buy a present for, and be bought a present by, someone else on the list (names_in_hat in code below).

The code below has several print calls there to help me work out what was going on.

The code seems to run fine (rejecting pairs on the exemption list as they appear and re-drawing) until all names on the list appear without hitting any exemptions.  At this point i was expecting the programe to just finish (as the for loop has hit the end of its range), but i periodically see several more - seemingly random itterations of the loop appearing, and i cant work out why...?

I have now got the programme working as i want it, after adding `raise SystemExit(0)` on line 47, which (as i understand it) just stops the programme as soon as the full list of paired names has been generated.

Anyway, can anyone tell me why the original version (as below, with the `raise SystemExit(0)` commented out) carrys on beyond what i was expecting to be the final list?

Thanks

```
# script to draw pairs of names 'from a hat' for a 'secret' santa
# certain pairs are not allowed

import random

# names for the draw
names_in_hat = ['Ross', 'Rachel', 'Monica', 'Chandler', 'Joey', 'Phoebe']

# the pairs not allowed
# note this only evaluates pairs EXACTLY as they are shown, i.e. 
# ['Ross', 'Rachel'] isnt same as ['Rachel', 'Ross']
exclusions = [['Ross', 'Rachel'],['Monica', 'Chandler'], ['Joey', 'Phoebe']]

# function to make the draw
def draw(names):

    random.shuffle(names) #shuffle the deck
    #print(names)


    # create empty list to store the drawn pairs
    pairs = []

    #select pairs of names and check if they are in the exclusions list
    for i in range(len(names)):

        if i == len(names)-1:
            D1 = names[i]
            D2 = names[0]
        else:
            D1 = names[i]
            D2 = names[i + 1]

#       THere will be a more elegant way of checkin the selection, regardless of order...
        select_a = [D1, D2]
        select_b = [D2, D1]

        if select_a in exclusions or select_b in exclusions:
            print("**PAIR", select_a, "NOT ALLOWED**")
            print("")
            draw(names) #re-shuffle and re-draw
        else:
            pairs.append(select_a)
            print(i, pairs)

    #print(pairs)
    #raise SystemExit(0) 

draw(names_in_hat)
```

Comment: Do you have to use recursion?

Comment: Recursion here is a bad idea; you just want some sort of `while` loop.

Comment: After the recursive call completes (which would appear to you that the process is finished), the call that *made* the recursive call continues, which would account for the additional activity you are observing. You aren't recognizing that you yourself should return after the recursive call returns.

Comment: You're using recursion, so you end up with several runs of `draw` on the stack. Even after one finishes, the others can still carry on running.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  Will do some googling around recursion (bit of a python noob).  Will also take a look at while loop.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this question was downvoted? I followed guidelines as best I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others suggested in comments, you have an issue with the recursive call being in a loop that usually doesn't finish right afterwards. Introduce a `break` or `return` right after the recursive call, and pass the list as parameter to function (add another formal parameter for it) (lists are passed by reference and are mutable).

Comment: not sure i understand (getting lost in language) - should i be passing the original list (names_in_hat) to the (recursive?) call to draw?

Comment: thanks michal - simply adding the break after the recursive call has fixed it

Comment: Am i correct in thinking this is because (to @khelwood point above) whilst this part of the loop is re-calling the draw() function, the original call is (in the absence of the break) still running?

Comment: Yes. And in main (outside of function) you can first declare a variable of empty list and then pass it to the call in main. And yes.

Comment: A call is recursive when it is a part of the definition of the function called. Now, I no longer remember why i wanted to mention what follows so disregard what follows: In the past there were language that didn't allow that because a function was not registered until it was fully defined, and then there were languages that introduced a separate type of function definition for recursive functions (i.e. functions that contain a recursive call).